# Play framework - access Request object inside java controller?

Tags: java, playframework

How do I access the request object inside my java controller in the play framework?

The Scala tutorial-page references some sort of "request" object, but I don't see how to access that in the Java tutorial-page.

I'm using Play Framework 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is really clear and straightforward:

When you call `request()` you access to the requests object, like headers and body, example `request().body()`

Much more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers

Comment: i mean, i like your answer (it answers the question, even with an example!) - but it is passive aggressive, and thus rude. The page you link is *riddled* with facts, and it, to me, when i search for "request" using the play search - it is not obvious where to look. I'm not sure how you found that page, but "body parser" is not something intuitive for "request". This isn't *your* fault, you didn't write the page - but, in making your answer belittling you impact the spread of knowledge (asking is important to transfer too), and also, de-facto defend this terrible documentation.

Comment: @bharal sorry, i not meant to be aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

Just add explicitly type: Action { request: Request[_] => ... }

Comment: Please use proper formatting and collaborate your answer!